# Custom LinearLayout is not displaying the "contents" properly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I created a custom LinearLayout. When I fill the content, the content displays outside of my custom LinearLayout. I would like the elements placed in the custom LinearLayout content to display inside of the custom LinearLayout.

Ie:

```
<"i am the tag">"i am the content"</"im part of the tag">
```

On a LinearLayout anything placed on the "content" displays inside of the layout. For some reason this is not working with custom LinearLayout.

My XML File

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundBase"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.obdgenie.programmer.Views.AppCardContainer
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="Test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.obdgenie.programmer.Views.AppCardContainer>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My Custom Class

```
public class AppCardContainer extends LinearLayout {

    public AppCardContainer(Context cont, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs){
        super(cont, attrs);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater.from(cont).inflate(R.layout.a_card_container, this);

    }

}
```

The Current Result
[image]

As requested. a_card_container XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect2"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/myrect"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aCardTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="@string/def"
            android:textColor="#f5f5f5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Mind you, I did have just a plain LinearLayout nothing else, and still got the same results.

Comment: Could you please add the R.layout.a_card_container file too?

Comment: I updated the question with the XML requested. Mind you, this XML was plain just LinearLayout, and it did not work either.